# How to get status code of a POST with Asp.Net HttpWebRequest

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest, search-engine, sitemap, webrequest

I'm trying to ping Google when my web site's sitemap is updated but I need to know which status code does Google or any other service returns. My code is below:

```
HttpWebRequest rqst = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://search.yahooapis.com/ping?sitemap=http%3a%2f%2fhasangursoy.com.tr%2fsitemap.xml");
rqst.Method = "POST";
rqst.ContentType = "text/xml";
rqst.ContentLength = 0;
rqst.Timeout = 3000;

rqst.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the response - assign it to a [`HttpWebResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse_members%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) variable:

```
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)rqst.GetResponse();
HttpStatusCode respStatusCode = resp.StatusCode;
```

The [`HttpStatusCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode.aspx) enumeration will tell you what status code was returned.

Comment: Code is ok but I get "OK" as status code. I needed code like 200, 404 etc.

Comment: I'ts done. If I use int respStatusCode = resp.StatusCode; this returns the status code. For more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode.aspx

Comment: @Hasan Gürsoy - it is an enumeration, so yes, it will be implicitly cast to an integer.

Comment: @Hasan Gürsoy - glad to have been of help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try HttpWebResponse.StatusCode out